# Open in Org Mode attached files in external programs doesn't work

Tags: org-mode, attachment

When I open an attached file in Org Mode with <kbd>C-a o</kbd> or its directory with <kbd>C-a f</kbd> it always opens in Emacs instead of the right external program or file browser.

[ What do I mean with "attached": I attach files to an outline with <kbd>C-a c</kbd> (or <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>m</kbd> or...).  ]

<s>What can I do about that?</s> Problem ist solved.

The Problem appeared in the combination of Ubuntu 17.10 and Emacs 25.2 (or whatever is shipped with Ubuntu 17.10, definitel > 25).

With Windows 10 / Emacs 25.3 and Ubuntu 16.04.3 / emacs 24 shortcuts do what they should do.

Comment: „right external program” severely depends on individual taste –– for many Emacs users, that's Emacs ;-)  Take a look at the org manual's hacking section (`C-h i m org`),  it shows you how to alter org's behaviour.  Or, browse the additional org packages at elpa/melpa for an org-plugin which does what you'd prefer.

Comment: You are right, but Emacs offers two options to open attached files with C-a: C-a o opens a an attached file (wherever...) and C-a O forces to open the file wihin Emacs. Even with your reading hints i don't know what to do to solve my problem. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried using `C-h k` and entering the key combo you use to open attachments?  usually, it tells about variables, and often about how to customize them or which defaults they use.  If you follow this chain a bit, you'll end up with a variable or list you simply need to edit (or customize via the customize menu).

Comment: Even the problem doesn't exist anymore, your answer was very helpful for me in terms of learning more about Emacs and how to solve problems. Thanks for that! A little more information what I found out with your help: told me that the lisp function org-attach.el is responsible for attaching Documents and the shortcut above did let me take a look at this function. So I find out that perhaps with the customization of the variable 'org-file-apps' I could solve my problem. Thanks, next time I know what to do.